# How to set imageview dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout, audio-player, albumart, android-music-player

I'm making a music player in android studio and I would like to do something like this

[Here's an ugly draw of what I'm attempting to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmFXC.png)

The black rectangle is the phone. I've already made the yellow part and now I have to set up the imageview as the one in the draw but I don't understand what kind of properties I have to type.

Here's the code i've made:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/song"
    android:layout_gravity="top" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img_album_cover"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/song_playback_buttons"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad English (I'm Italian).

Answer (score 0):

First you're going to want it to fill the space in between your top and bottom layouts, so make the width/height of the ImageView to fill_parent.

Next, you'll want to give it an `android:layout_weight="1"` as well, so it doesn't push the bottom layout off the screen.

Now for the actual image, you'll want to add `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` to the ImageView. This will cause the source image to be scaled (from the center, maintaining aspect ratio) so that the width/height of the image will fill or extend beyond the boundaries of the View.

Edit: you can also remove all the layout_gravity attributes, as the layout_weight will render them useless.

Comment: Wow thank you, that was very useful!
Now it seems to work great!